# what happens to my theme when I upload it to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, themes, zip

After I created a theme for wordpress, i zipped it and tried to upload it while wordpress theme upload option. And when I click install I get this error

[image: wordpress theme upload fail]

what could possible be the reason of this error?

Answer (score 0):

One common cause that is possible, as discussed [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/incompatible-archive-pclzip_err_bad_format-10), is that you don't have enough storage space free on your server.